# Register sistem is not working (Undefined variable: link)

Tags: php, html

I'm using John Morris' code for login system from 2013, this is the `db.php` file where I think is the problem, I just don't know how to fix it.

```
<?php
    if(!class_exists('TejaMarketDatabase')) {   
        class TejaMarketDatabase { 
            function TejaMarketDatabase() {
                return $this->_construct();
            } 
            function _construct() {
                $this->connect();
            }
            function connect() {
                $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
                if (!$link) {
                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
                }
                $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);
                if (!$db_selected) {
                    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error($link));
                }
            }
            function clean($array) {
                return array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $array);
            }
            function hash_password($password, $nonce) {
                $secureHash = hash_hmac('sha512', $password . $nonce, SITE_KEY);
                return $secureHash;
            }
            function insert($link, $table, $fields, $values) {
                $fields = implode(", ", $fields);
                $values = implode("', '", $values);
                $sql="INSERT INTO $table (id, $fields) VALUES ('', '$values')";
                if (!mysqli_query($sql)) {
                    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
                } else {
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }    
            function select($sql) {
                $results = mysqli_query($sql);
                return $results;
            }
        }
    } 
    //Instantiate our database class
    $tmdb = new TejaMarketDatabase;
?>
```

It might be that the connect function is not being called, but I can't get with the why.

I thought that it could be the `_construct()` because I changed it from `__construct()` because it was giving me an error too; so I have no idea how to call the connect method properly.

Comment: First of all your code is open to a SQL injection attack use prepared statements. And it would be more helpful if you could post the error message you're getting.

Comment: You need to go back and rename it back to `__construct()`

Comment: Then remove the same named method as class name. That is deprecated in the newest php, just stick with the `___construct()` as the initializing method

Comment: Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` for the password saving and matching.

Comment: Also which line is saying undefined??

Comment: it's just the link variable.
it says line 21, 31 and 32, but they are just using the variable as a parameter
Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /db.php on line 32, for example